# output of two dimensional array is not outputting correctly

Tags: c

I am trying to read a `.txt` file and arrange the strings in the file to a two dimensional array and display the output.

i have tried a `nested for loop` to arrange the input and to display the output.

```
char L[1000];
char ALL[8][1000];

char* filename = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\NNCENTERS.txt";
FILE *F;

F =fopen(filename, "r");

if(F == NULL){
  printf("Couldnt open file %s", filename);
}

while(fscanf(F, "%s", L) != EOF){
  for(int j=0; j<8;j++){
    for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){
      if(L[i] == 'h' ){
        j++;
      }else{
        ALL[j][i]=L[i];
      }
    }
  }
}

for (int m = 0;  m< 8 ; m++) {
    for (int n = 0; n < 50; n++) {
        printf("%c ", ALL[m][n]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

the process is terminated without results...
 my .txt file is

```
Q 2.55555 5.66699 0.22245 0 0 h
P 2.13244 5.66699 0.22245 0 1 h
E 2.82555 5.66699 0.22245 0 2 h
R 2.55125 5.66699 0.22245 1 0 h
T 2.58493 5.66699 0.22245 1 1 h
Y 2.55512 5.66699 0.22245 1 2 h
U 2.52545 5.66699 0.22245 2 0 h
I 2.12455 5.66699 0.22245 2 1 h
O 2.55124 5.66699 0.22245 2 2 h
```

Comment: Two dimensional arrays don't really exist in C. See some [C reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c) and the C11 standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). They are just arrays of arrays. Read [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). StackOverflow is not a *fix-my-buggy-code* service

Comment: well thank you for mentioning it, but i know that. what i am asking is i made an array of arrays with a counter but its not copying my values correctly why?

Comment: Please learn to use your debugger. For example [debug with `gdb`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/). BTW strings in C are terminated with `\0` (the nul byte) and you don't handle or enforce that. Notice that your `ALL` array is *never* initialized so contain garbage values. Avoid such [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: @KARAMJABER I proposed a corrected and simplified way to do, please look at my answer

Comment: You can't use `while(fscanf(F, "%s", L) != EOF)` it will stop reading at the first whitespace. You should read the entire line at a time with `fgets` and trim the trailing `'\n'` and then loop `for (i = 0; ; i++) { ALL[j][i] = L[i]; if (!L[i]) break; }` to fill your 2d array with that row. (or simply use `strcpy`)

Comment: OT:  variable (and parameter) names should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both).  names like `ALL` `F` `L` are meaningless, even in the current context.

Comment: OT: regarding statements like: `printf("Couldnt open file %s", filename);` 1) error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`  2) when the error indication comes from a C library function, should also output the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  The function: `perror();` correctly handles all of this.

Comment: when an unrecoverable error occurs, as in: `if(F == NULL){
  printf("Couldnt open file %s", filename);
}`  then (besides calling `perror()` to properly handle the error messages) the next statement should be `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  The code should not continue to execute as if the (in this case) call to `fopen()` were successful  Note: `exit()` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are both from the `stdlib.h` header file

Comment: regarding: `while(fscanf(F, "%s", L) != EOF){`  there are other reasons that the call to `fscanf()` can fail other than EOF.  Suggest: `while(fscanf(F, "%999s", L) == 1){`  When using the input format specifer '%s' and/or '%[...]' always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is one less than the length of the input field because those specifiers always append a NUL byte to the end of the input.  A benefit is that the input buffer can never overflow, thus avoiding any possibility of any undefined behavior

Comment: Per your question, there are 9 rows /lines in the input file, but the data declaration for `ALL[][]` is only allowing for 8 rows/lines. So when the last line of the file is read, the data will be placed past the end of the array, resulting in undefined behavior.  Suggest: 1) increase the number '8' to '9'  2) and for speed, use 'fgets()' rather than 'fscanf()`.  Also, the call to `fscanf()` will stop when it hits the first white space.  (cont)

Comment: (cont) I.E. when it encounters the space in `Q 2.55555`, etc.  So each call to `fscanf()` will only input a VERY few characters.  Suggest using the format string; " %999[\n]"  Notice the leading space to consume any 'white space' that might be left over from a prior call to `fscanf()`

Comment: regarding: `for (int m = 0;  m< 8 ; m++) {`  this only allows the first 8 lines to be printed.  However, per your question, there are 9 lines.  Strongly suggest `for (int m = 0;  m < i ; m++) {`

Comment: to make accurate printing easy, suggest the definition of `ALL` be modified to:  `#define MAX_LINES 9  #define MAX_LINE_LEN 1000  char ALL[ MAX_LINES ][ MAX_LINE_LEN ] = {'\0'};`  Then the print loop would only have a single line in its' body: `printf( "%s\n", ALL[m] );

Comment: the posted code fails to place the trailing 'H' of each line into the `ALL[][]` array.   The question does not state that the trailing 'H' is to be ignored, so this needs to be corrected

Comment: oops, this line ` Suggest using the format string; " %999[\n]"` should be: ` Suggest using the format string; " %999[^\n]"`

Comment: strongly suggest replacing the whole `while( fscanf...` code block with: `#define MAX_LINES 9 ......int i=0; while( i < MAX_LINES && fscanf( F, " %999[%\n]", ALL[i] ) == 1) { i++;}

Comment: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis. I.E. 8, 1000.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest giving those 'magic' numbers meaningful names via `#define` statements or an `enum` statement, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your loop must stop at the end of the read line, but you you continue looking at 1000 characters generally going out of read char in L

```
for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){
  if(L[i] == 'h' ){
    j++;
  }else{
    ALL[j][i]=L[i];
  }
}
```

must be like

```
for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){
  if (L[i] == 'h') {
    // may be something to do
    j++;
    break;
  }else{
    ALL[j][i]=L[i];
  }
}
```

and in

```
for (int m = 0;  m< 8 ; m++) {
  for (int n = 0; n < 50; n++) {
      printf("%c ", ALL[m][n]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

if the read lines have less than 50 characters you will print random char

so in read loop better to save 0 at the end of string (`ALL[j][i] = 0;` in place at my comment) and finally just do

```
for (int m = 0;  m< 8 ; m++) {
  printf("%s\n", &ALL[m][0]);
}
```

Anyway there is an other problem, each time you read a line you write from the beginning of ALL, so only the last line will be save !

Note also that even you read well the array is only able to memorize 8 lines while your file has 9 lines, and the easier way to read a line is to use fgets

---

if I do fixes and some simplifications the result can be :

```
#define NLINES 8 /*needs more probably*/
#define LINELENGTH 1000

char ALL[NLINES][LINELENGTH];

const char* filename = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\NNCENTERS.txt";
FILE *F = fopen(filename, "r");

if(F == NULL){
  printf("Couldnt open file %s\n", filename);
}
else {
  char (*p)[LINELENGTH] = ALL;

  while (fgets(*p, sizeof(*p), F) != 0) {
    int len = strlen(*p);

    // remove '\n' if present at end of line
    if ((len > 1) && ((*p)[len - 1] == '\n'))
      (*p)[--len] = 0;

    // remove 'h' if present at end of line
    if ((len > 1) && ((*p)[len - 1] == 'h'))
      (*p)[len - 1] = 0;

    if (++p == &ALL[NLINES])
      break;
  }

  fclose(F);

  for (int m = 0;  m< NLINES ; m++) {
    printf("%s\n", ALL[m]);
  }
}
```

Comment: this answer has the problem that when the call to `fopen()` fails, 1) the code has an unrecoverable error, but does not output the text reason the system thinks the error occurred AND it continues to execute the code as if the call to `fopen()` were successful

Answer (score 2):

in c when you declare any array it just contains garbage values,
I see that you declared `char ALL[8][50];` but never assigned any meaningful values to it, so when you do `L[i]=ALL[j][i];` the meaningful value in `L[i]` is replaced with garbage value.

hence it prints garbage on the screen.

I think you might wanna do `ALL[j][i] = L[i]`

**edit:**

You defined L as 1000 sized array and ALL as 8x50
but when you do `for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){` and then you access ALL[j][i], it just goes out of bounds,

you should have ALL as `ALL[8][1000]`

Comment: the other problem is _i_ going out of the array in `ALL[j][i]` because _i_ goes up to 999 while the dimension is only 50

Comment: you are right, but each line in my text file only goes to 50 and its limited to go only to 50 and then write an "h" which is my string terminator in this case. which why i considered putting them in the same loop.

Comment: @Auxilus thank you, but with the edited code, same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You make things much more difficult than they need to be. You have a 2D array with `8` rows and `1000` characters per-row. You can use `fgets` to read directly into each row of the array by simply keeping a row counter. Then all that remains is trimming the `'\n'` from the end of each line (which you do by overwriting that character with the nul-character `0`)

Putting it altogether you could do something like the following that takes the filename to read as the first argument to the program (don't hard-code filenames), or the program with read from `stdin` (by default) if no filename is given:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ROW    8    /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define COL 1000

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char all[ROW][COL] = { "" };    /* 2D array of char */
    int nrow = 0;                   /* row index */
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    /* read each line protecting array bounds */
    while (nrow < ROW && fgets (all[nrow], COL, fp)) {
        all[nrow][strcspn (all[nrow], "\n")] = 0;       /* trim '\n' */
        nrow++;     /* increment row count */
    }
    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file if not stdin */

    for (int i = 0; i < nrow; i++)
        printf ("all[%d] : %s\n", i, all[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/read2dfile <dat/2dfile.txt
all[0] : Q 2.55555 5.66699 0.22245 0 0 h
all[1] : P 2.13244 5.66699 0.22245 0 1 h
all[2] : E 2.82555 5.66699 0.22245 0 2 h
all[3] : R 2.55125 5.66699 0.22245 1 0 h
all[4] : T 2.58493 5.66699 0.22245 1 1 h
all[5] : Y 2.55512 5.66699 0.22245 1 2 h
all[6] : U 2.52545 5.66699 0.22245 2 0 h
all[7] : I 2.12455 5.66699 0.22245 2 1 h
```

(**note:** only 8-lines are read despite there being 9-lines in your input file. By properly protecting your array bounds, you can properly fill your array regardless of the number of lines in your input file)

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.